# Rails application not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I returned to my first hello world Rails program from Hartyl tutorial and I tried to run the application which had previously worked perfectly and displayed 'Hello World'. This time it doesn't run and when I go to Share and try to open the url, it says it couldn't find the application.

Any ideas why this would happen? I tried to run the rails server command from scratch and went back over the instructions but hasn't solved it.

Would appreciate any help and your patience, thanks.

*Wish I could give more info. This is the first program I've done in Rails and first time I've returned to a program after a mini hiatus in Rails so I expected it to run as it did before when I returned to the Cloud9 IDE that the tutorial uses. In general, should this just run as it did before, or is it normal that you have to start back in the terminal again to see it running in the url?

Comment: Can you give more info please?

Comment: Can you please past the logs from `rails s` command?

Comment: Look in your `log/development.log` file.

Comment: First of all make sure you are in the directory of the your rails app in Cloud9 (This directory is where the `app`, `config`, `public` folders are).
Once you're in that folder, in the Cloud9 terminal, 1) what is the exact output when you run `rails server`? 2) what is the exact error message as shown when you browse the page?

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario The error on the browsing page is: No application seems to be running here. Check that the workspace name (rails-tutorial) and username (xxx) are typed correctly.
Check that the server is successfully running on Cloud9:
If the server hit an error, the output window will have a message telling you what it is
If you're in the middle of debugging code, your server might be paused right now
The server might be running on a different port; make sure it's on port $PORT with $IP as the IP address.

Comment: I just registered in Cloud9 now just to try simulate your error. I managed to replicate your error (No application seems to be running here!). This happens when I stop the `rails s -p $PORT -b $IP`. After running the server again in the command line in Cloud9 workspace, it works again as expected. 1) Do you close the `rails s` command? Make sure you do not stop it. 2) What is shown in the console after you type `rails s -b-p $PORT -b $IP`? It shoud be something like the following: `=> Booting WEBrick ...  INFO Webrick 1.3.1 ... INFO Webrick::HTTPServer#start pid=1176 port=8080

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario When I do that I just get this back (I omitted a lot):       
  Usage: rails new APP_PATH [options]
Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice.....
                                                         # Default: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-
    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.
....
    This generates a skeletal Rails installation.....
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.

Comment: @shinninja Hi I simulated your error. And found out that this text you see after running `rails s -p $PORT -b $IP` happens when you  are not inside the rails application directory. Can you check what directory is in your command line in C9? Make sure you're inside the Rails application directory, and that you should see something like this in the console `myusername@my-workspace-name:~/workspace/my-rails-project`, and that it should not be: `myusername@my-workspace-name:~/workspace`

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario Yes you are right - it is myusername@my-workspace-name:~/workspace – that I am seeing! How can I get back inside the rails application directory?

Comment: @shinninja you can do that by `cd my-rails-project` cd means change directory

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario Ok, got it, thanks a lot! Sorry but I had mistakenly taken the top level name of the project instead of the secondary application name when I tried to cd into it. I'm now getting this error when I do the rails s -b-p $PORT -b $IP again: You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements.
You specified: sass-rails (~> 5.0) and sass-rails (= 5.0.2)

Comment: Ohh that means in your `Gemfile` you have a line `gem sass-rails, ~> 5.0` and another line `gem sass-rails, 5.0.2` you cannot have same-named gems twice or more in that file. You can safely remove the line `gem sass-rails, ~> 5.0`, and after that, run `bundle install`, and after that again finally and hopefully `rails s -p $PORT -b $IP` will now work

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario Really sorry about this but I removed the gem sass-rails, ~> 5.0 line and I still have the exact same error back after I ran bundle install.